# What's the difference between a gemspec summary and a gemspec description?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When you write a gemspec file, what is the practical difference, if any, between the summary and description fields?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They are used in different places. `summary` is seen you do `gem list -d`, while `description` is seen on http://rubygems.org. Description "should be more detailed than summary" (http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/), but in reality you see

```
s.description = s.summary
```

in `.gemspec`s a lot.

Comment: Note, when the description and summary are set to the same value, you'll get a warning while packaging the gem (at least with recent versions of rubygems).

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question, but I found my way here.

[Per the reference](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/), the description is optional and the summary is required. So I define a summary but no description.